# How do I make a method that inserts dashes into a string in a looping pattern?

Tags: java, methods

For context, the method needs to insert dashes into a string in a 1, 2, 4, 1, 2, 4... pattern. For example, a string that holds "Overflow" would be output as "O-ve-rflo-w". Would I use nested for loops in this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answer using a pattern is a great solution, however, you could also use a recursive method. This may not be a compact solution, but the logic is easy to follow:

```
//Process the string in chunks of 7 characters
public static String addFormatting(String input){
    String formatted = "";
    
    //Add first character
    if(input.length() >= 1) formatted = input.substring(0, 1);
    
    //Add dash and the next 2 characters, else the remainder of the string
    if(input.length() >= 3) formatted += "-" + input.substring(1,3);
    else if (input.length() > 1) formatted += "-" + input.substring(1);
    
    //Add dash and the next 4 characters, else the remainder of the string
    if(input.length() >= 7) formatted += "-" + input.substring(3,7);
    else if (input.length() > 3) formatted += "-" + input.substring(3);
    
    //Add dash and recursivly format the next chunk
    if(input.length() > 7){
        formatted += "-";
        return formatted + addFormatting(input.substring(7));
    }
    //else return the complete formatted once it has been fully processed
    else return formatted;
}
```

To call the method simply use `addFormatting("OverflowisagreatQnAsite!");` the printed output would `O-ve-rflo-w-is-agre-a-tQ-nAsi-t-e!`

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

```
private static String applyPattern(List<Integer> pattern, String str) {
    int currentPatternIndex = 0;
    int iterationsTillNextDash = pattern.get(currentPatternIndex);
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    
    for (char aChar : str.toCharArray()) {
        if (iterationsTillNextDash == 0) {
            stringBuilder.append('-');
            iterationsTillNextDash = pattern.get(++currentPatternIndex % pattern.size());
        }

        iterationsTillNextDash--;
        stringBuilder.append(aChar);
    }
    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

Usage:

```
String strWithDashes = applyPattern(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 4), "Overflow");
System.out.println(strWithDashes);
```

Output:

```
O-ve-rflo-w
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple hard-coded example for your situation. Perhaps you can figure out a way to use modulus `%` in your code for words longer than "overflow".

```
class Main {
  public static String addDashes(String s)
  {
    String s_with_dashes = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    {
      if(i == 1 || i == 3 || i == 7)
      {
        s_with_dashes += '-';
      } 
      s_with_dashes += s.charAt(i);   
    }
    return s_with_dashes;
  }
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String s = "Overflow";
    String s_with_dashes = addDashes(s);
    System.out.println(s_with_dashes);
  }
}
```

Comment: Fails e.g. for text `OverflowOverflowOverflow`, by not repeating the pattern. Actual: `O-ve-rflo-wOverflowOverflow`, Expected: `O-ve-rflo-w-Ov-erfl-o-wO-verf-l-ow`

Comment: @Andreas I literally said I hardcoded it for his situation and recommended a possible solution for words longer than "Overflow" :/

Comment: Yes, you hardcoded the 1,2,4 pattern, which is valid, since question didn't list that as dynamic. The `"Overflow"` text is however explicitly listed as an *example*, so hardcoding the logic to only handle that one example is **not useful** *(so gains a down-vote)*. --- You also skipped a big part of the problem, i.e. the part where the pattern is *repeating*, again making the answer **not useful** *(another reason for down-vote)*.

Answer (score 0):

Method:

```
private static String addDashes(String string, int... pattern) {
    String output = "";
    int index = 0;

    while (true)
        for (int p : pattern) {
            if (index + p >= string.length())
                return output += string.substring(index);
            output += string.substring(index, index += p) + "-";
        }
}
```

Call Method:

```
System.out.println(addDashes("Overflow", 1,2,4));
```

Output:

```
O-ve-rflo-w
```